# RSpec does run after upgrade to Rails 5.1.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I've updated my application to Rails 5.1.5 after resolving all errors and depreciations in 5.0. Now, I get this message when I run RSpec:

block in materialize': Could not find activesupport-5.1.5 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

ActiveSupport-5.1.5 is present in gemfile.lock:
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    Ascii85 (1.0.3)
    actioncable (5.1.5)
      actionpack (= 5.1.5)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (~> 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.1.5)
      actionpack (= 5.1.5)
      actionview (= 5.1.5)
      activejob (= 5.1.5)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.1.5)
      actionview (= 5.1.5)
      activesupport (= 5.1.5)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.1.5)
      activesupport (= 5.1.5)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activeadmin (1.2.1)
      arbre (>= 1.1.1)
      coffee-rails
      formtastic (~> 3.1)
      formtastic_i18n
      inherited_resources (~> 1.7)
      jquery-rails (>= 4.2.0)
      kaminari (>= 0.15, < 2.0)
      railties (>= 4.2, < 5.2)
      ransack (~> 1.3)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (< 4.1)
    activejob (5.1.5)
      activesupport (= 5.1.5)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.1.5)
      activesupport (= 5.1.5)
    activerecord (5.1.5)
      activemodel (= 5.1.5)
      activesupport (= 5.1.5)
      arel (~> 8.0)
    activesupport (5.1.5)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.5.2)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 4.0)
    afm (0.2.2)

I'm running RSpec 3.7.1
Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this? The application runs fine on my server!

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your bundle correctly and resolved dependencies? Most of the times, you have to update the gems which are deprecated with your new version of rails upgrade.